# How to Windows primary disk, alpine linux secondary disk grub dual boot?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, alpine-linux

I decided to try out running alpine linux as a desktop system, intrigued by its minimalist nature.

Problem: I need to write grub to the MBR of the Windows disk `sda`, such that it looks at the /boot on the secondary disk `sdb`, and can boot either windows or linux from the grub menu it finds there.  Currently booting off of sda goes straight to Windows, booting off of sdb does get me a Grub menu, but both options seem to go boot linux.

My setup:

- Windows 10 is on the primary drive, /dev/sda
- alpine 3.10.1 is on the secondary drive, /dev/sdb; with the /boot directory on the /dev/sdb1 partition.

I did:

```
# removes default bootloader, I don't think handles different disks
$ apk del syslinux

# install grub, bios version
$ apk add grub grub-bios
$ grub-install /dev/sdb
```

I have this in my /etc grub file 40_custom:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

I've seen documentation that says doing a `grub-install /dev/sda` would install to the MBR, but am worried grub-install does more than this, and will trash Windows, thinking there's a /boot directory there also to stuff it's files in.

The confusing thing to me is that I've come across lots of documentation that refers to an `update-grub2` command, like this: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Alpine_on_HDD_dualbooting, which is **nowhere** on my alpine linux installation.  Nor do I have the base `grub` command, only `grub-*` commands.  So I feel like grub's changed since the last time I've used it directly (probably 10 years ago, so I'm a bit rusty), or maybe the alpine package is missing something.

I'm probably missing something small, as I feel it's *almost* there, but not quite.

Comment: The normal way to do this is to leave the primary drive untouched, put GRUB on the secondary drive, set the boot priority for the secondary drive to be checked first, then get to either OS via GRUB.  I'm missing why you would need or want to do it differently.

Comment: Can't be that different, I just had NixOS on this 2nd partition, and it's bootlaoder (I think GRUB) handled this case no problem.  I've had Ubuntu handle this case as well.  But I guess I've never buckled down and understood exactly how they handle this case, (and GRUB 2 seems different now) so thus my question in coming to Alpine.

Comment: "Can't be that different": It sounds like doing what I described worked for you, then you did all this and now it doesn't work.  The amount different is that it used to work and now it doesn't; that's the difference.  Go back to what works.  :-)